# Calculating Pair wise distance for each instance using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe which looks like this

[image: my dataframe]

I wanted to create a new data frame with pair-wise distances for each instance using for loop
I used the following code to create pair-wise distance

```
list=[]            
list2=[]            
list3=[]                
for i in df.index:   
    for j in df.index:             
        list.append(i)             
        list2.append(j)               
        
for z in range(0,5):
    for y in range(0,5):
        list3.append(distance.jaccard(df.iloc[z],df.iloc[y]))


Se=pd.Series(list)
Se2=pd.Series(list2)
Se3=pd.Series(list3)
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':Se,'B':Se2,'Distance':Se3})
```

But my result was

[image: new_dataframe]

Expected ouput

```
A-B-Distance                    
Instance_0 - Instance_1- 0.5           
Instance_0 - Instance_2 - 0.0         
Instance_0 - Insatnce_3 - 0.5       
Instance_0 - Instance_4 -0.5       
Instance_1 - Instance_2 - 0.5       
Instance_1 - Instance_3 - 0.0          
Insatnce_1 - Instance_4 - 1.0          
Instance_2 - Instance_3 - 0.5            
Instance_2 - Instance_4 - 0.5           
instance_3 - Instance_4 - 1.0
```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: you have to describe difference between your output and expected output. Outputs are long and we may not see difference - and we can't read in your mind.

Comment: for normal list it would need to use first index in second `for`-loop - `for ... in range(first_index, n)` instead of `for ... in range(n)` - and this should skip pairs like `(1,0)` because you already have pair `(0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand difference between outputs you want to skip pairs like `(a,a)` and also keep `(a,b)` but remove `(b,a)`

Simply in second `for`-loop you have to use `range(z+1, 5)` instead of `range(0, 5)`

```
for z in range(0, 5):
    for y in range(z+1, 5):
        print(z, y)
```

Result:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```